# traveling ruby tutorial wrapper is erroring

Tags: ruby

I am having an issue understanding part of the tutorial for traveling ruby.

https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby/blob/master/TUTORIAL-1.md

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

# Figure out where this script is located.
SELFDIR="`dirname \"$0\"`"
SELFDIR="`cd \"$SELFDIR\" && pwd`"

# Run the actual app using the bundled Ruby interpreter.
exec "$SELFDIR/lib/ruby/bin/ruby" "$SELFDIR/lib/app/hello.rb"
```

When I copy and paste this it doesn't seem to work and I am not sure what the end result is supposed to be, I don't see how this will look through directories and find my script, which is what the comment implies(# Figure out where this script is located.). I can't see why it isn't working.

The result I get from pasting it is:

```
dirname: illegal option -- b
usage: dirname path
Saving session...
...copying shared history...
...saving history...truncating history files...
...completed.

[Process completed]
```

Comment: when you say "pasting it" what do you mean? Did you run this successfully?  https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby/blob/master/TUTORIAL-1.md#quick-sanity-testing

Answer (score -1):

Follow the instructions exactly in order to get the expected results.  There is one step which may throw you off in the instructions assuming you're on a Mac and ran the sanity check.  You will need to do `cd ..` to move up one directory before doing the next step where you'll need to create a file in the proper directory.  It should be in `hello_app/packaging/wrapper.sh`  This is a shell script which will handle packaging the app into its respective folders.  It is not a ruby script and can't be executed by ruby or in a ruby IRB console etc.

Make sure you're in the the root of `hello_app` folder before you tar up the sub directories as instructed here: https://github.com/phusion/traveling-ruby/blob/master/TUTORIAL-1.md#finalizing-packages

That happens with these commands:

```
tar -czf hello-1.0.0-linux-x86.tar.gz hello-1.0.0-linux-x86
tar -czf hello-1.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz hello-1.0.0-linux-x86_64
tar -czf hello-1.0.0-osx.tar.gz hello-1.0.0-osx
rm -rf hello-1.0.0-linux-x86
rm -rf hello-1.0.0-linux-x86_64
rm -rf hello-1.0.0-osx
```

If you do everything correctly you'll end up with a directory structure like:

```
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff  5936573 Apr 11 20:17 hello-1.0.0-linux-x86.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff  6378021 Apr 11 20:17 hello-1.0.0-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff  6800089 Apr 11 20:17 hello-1.0.0-osx.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff       39 Apr 11 20:10 hello.rb
drwxr-xr-x  6 someone  staff      204 Apr 11 20:13 packaging/
hello_app % ll packaging
total 37328
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff  5945007 Apr 11 20:11 traveling-ruby-20141215-2.1.5-linux-x86.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff  6388408 Apr 11 20:11 traveling-ruby-20141215-2.1.5-linux-x86_64.tar.gz
-rw-r--r--  1 someone  staff  6769622 Apr 11 20:11 traveling-ruby-20141215-2.1.5-osx.tar.gz
-rwxr-xr-x  1 someone  staff      244 Apr 11 20:13 wrapper.sh*
```

Comment: No need to lead with rudeness